# Getting undefined reference to `floor' on running make in PintOS

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to run make on a PintOS makefile but I keep getting the undefined reference to `floor' error. The makefile is below. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with gcc 4.6.1. Any help is appreciated.

```
    all: setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix
    CC = gcc
    CFLAGS = -Wall -W
    LDFLAGS = -lm
    setitimer-helper: setitimer-helper.o
    squish-pty: squish-pty.o
    squish-unix: squish-unix.o

    clean: 
          rm -f *.o setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix
```

~

Comment: Make will print the exact commands it's invoking.  What is the exact command that it's running for GCC?

Comment: Probably the library is passed before the object file and the linker is in as-needed mode. Try with `gcc -o something something.o -lm`, or add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the compiler flags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-lm` should be in `LDLIBS`, not `LDFLAGS`.

The difference is important, because the implicit rule for linking executables is:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

and `ld` (invoked by GCC) has a strict left-to-right dependency-resolution algorithm.