# Unable to link math lib using a makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linker errors when compiling against glib…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib)

Okay, I know this may be a duplicate, but I can't find any other answer to my problem.
I am trying to install Pintos and when I run 'make' in the src/utils directory, I get the error that there is an undefined reference to 'floor'. I checked the makefile and here's what I got:

```
all: setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix
# 2207718881418

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -W
LDFLAGS = -lm
setitimer-helper: setitimer-helper.o
squish-pty: squish-pty.o
squish-unix: squish-unix.o

clean: 
    rm -f *.o setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix
```

I tried adding LIBS = -lm but that didn't help.

Output of make:

```
gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper
setitimer-helper.o: In function `main':
setitimer-helper.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [setitimer-helper] Error 1
```

Any solutions to this dilemma?

Comment: I can't see the full compiler command but libraries need to go at the end. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib/9966989#9966989

Comment: I am sorry, but don't think that helps. I simply run a make and it gives me that error.

Comment: Can you post the output of make, particularly the `gcc` line?

Comment: hmjd please see the question again.

Comment: In the output from `make`, notice the `-lm` is _not_ at the end of the compiler command. The problem is as I stated in my earlier comment.

Comment: So how do I change that? I am not very knowledgeable about the Makefile.

Comment: Varagrawal's _issue_ is that `-lm` is not at the end of the command as per @hmjd's suggested similar question, but his _question_ is about how to fix it while minimising changes to his makefile -- which the suggested duplicate doesn't address at all.  For actual duplicate questions, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963645/getting-undefined-reference-to-floor-on-running-make-in-pintos or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539153/how-to-follow-linking-order-when-linking-against-static-library-with-gnu-make

Comment: John Marshall, your first link is the exact duplicate. I couldn't find that on earlier searches maybe due to the lack of a PintOS tag, so thanks for it. And I had mentioned that my question may be a duplicate in the first line. ;-) :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original makefile defines a bunch of variables

```
CC = gcc
# etc
```

and lists some dependencies

```
setitimer-helper: setitimer-helper.o
# etc
```

but doesn't have any recipes giving the exact commands to be used to remake the targets, except for the `clean` rule.  This means that built-in implicit rules will be used; e.g., to link `setitimer-helper` the following built-in rule will be used:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

For `setitemer-helper`, the automatic variables are filled in using the relevant dependency:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) setitimer-helper.o $(LDLIBS) -o setitimer-helper
```

and from this you can see how the remaining variables -- `$(CC)`, `$(LDFLAGS)`, and `$(LDLIBS)` -- were filled in to give the output of make that you saw.

As various people have noted, you need to make sure that `-lm` goes at the **end** of the link command so that it can be used to satisfy references to library functions like `floor()`.  At the moment, your makefile sets `$(LDFLAGS)` to `-lm`, but that variable is used at the start of the link command.

The conventional variables are set up in this built-in rule so that `LDFLAGS` can be used for options (a.k.a. "flags") that (historically) need to be at the start of the link command, and `LDLIBS` can be used for libraries that need to be specified after the `*.o` object files.

So to fix this in terms of the makefile you are using, you need to remove `-lm` from the `LDFLAGS` variable that is defined, and instead add another variable definition for `LDLIBS`:

```
LDLIBS = -lm
```

(I'm oversummarising slightly: the built-in rule also contains `$(TARGET_ARCH)` and `$(LOADLIBES)`, but those aren't of interest here.)

Answer (score 1):

It's compiled in wrong order, the way to proceed is:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -W
LDFLAGS = -lm

myprog: myprog.o more_code.o
       ${CC} ${CFLAGS} myprog.o more_code.o ${LDFLAGS} -o myprog

myprog.o: myprog.c
       ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c myprog.c

more_code.o: more_code.c
       ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c more_code.c

clean:
       \rm myprog.o more_code.o myprog
```

More info: http://www.physics.utah.edu/~p5720/rsrc/make.html

Can you show me in terms of the original makefile?
I can try :)

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -W
LDFLAGS = -lm
OBJECTS = setitimer-helper.o squish-pty.o squish-unix.o

all: setitimer-helper

setitimer-helper: $(OBJECTS)
       ${CC} ${CFLAGS} $(OBJECTS) ${LDFLAGS} -o setitimer-helper

setitimer-helper.o: setitimer-helper.c
       ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c setitimer-helper.c

squish-pty.o: squish-pty.c
       ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c squish-pty.c

squish-unix.o: squish-unix.c
       ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c squish-unix.c
```

And since you are new to Makefile, it's a good idea to add -Wextra -pedantic to CFLAGS

Comment: I am not getting you. The makefile was given to me as part of a tarball. Can you show me in terms of the original makefile?

Comment: @Varagrawal instead of `$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) myprog.o -o myprog`, write `$(LD) myprog.o $(LDFLAGS) -o myprog`, so that the libraries go after the list of object files to be linked.

Comment: But that is not the way the Makefile was originally structured, and since I am new to makefiles, I have no clue how to make the correct changes.

Comment: Using LDLIBS instead of LDFLAGS should solve the problem without having to explicitly listing recipes for all targets (using implicit rules).  @john-marshall shows how to do that.

Comment: @RudyMatela, you are right, but I am just pointing the cause of error